# why does requests-html return content partialy?

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-requests, html-parsing

i know, that its's because of content, being rendered by js, but requests-html supports js, so that's strange

code itself:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
session.browser
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
r = session.get("https://readli.net/chitat-online/?b=439184&pg=1", headers = headers)
r.html.render(timeout = 13)
text = r.html.text
print(text)
```

Comment: I don't think there is that much JavaScript on that site. What data are you trying to scrape?

Comment: @juanpethes i'm trying to get the text in p tags

Comment: See my answer to achieve this, and feel free to ask any follow up questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML document, I got it to work. This module makes it easier to get out the stuff within the p-tags, which are spread throughout in a bunch of nested <li>, <div>, etc. tags in the plain HTML.

Hence this code gets the entire text within p-tags on the first page (as specified by `&pg=1` in the URL). (Note I also used `requests` instead of `requests_html` but it should be the same - I just didn't have `requests_html` installed. Try to replace it with `requests_html` and if it doesn't work, you know you at least have a solution with `requests`).

The reason I use a `with` statement is so the session is automatically closed after usage.

The `'\n'.join` is to print it out with newlines separating, rather than simply a long list of each p-tag.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get(
        "https://readli.net/chitat-online/?b=439184&pg=1", 
        headers = headers,
    )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print('\n'.join(ptag.text for ptag in soup.find_all('p')))
```

I hope this helps.